# Player performs differently across browsers

Tags: ios, firefox, google-chrome, mime-types, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to find a player that actually works with HTML5 and wordpress and yours has come close.

I'm on an Apache server hosted through godaddy.

The link below is the page I'm testing on. In Chrome it auto loads one version while still showing the play button. Upon hitting play, another version starts, thus two playing at once.

In firefox it just won't load at all. the poster frame shows, but video never plays (according to godaddy the ogg/ogv mime type is there.)

In safari it works fine.

http://parkmultimedia.com/test/

Here is the code i'm using -

[video mp4="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.mp4" webm="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.webm" ogg="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.ogg" flv="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.flv" poster="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/webstill.png" preload="true" autoplay="false" width="480" height="272" align="center"]

Any help would be appreciated!
Dan

**UPDATE**
OK, I've managed to get the above page to work after some tinkering. Chrome, Safari, Firefox all seem to work no. I'm going to have opera and PC friends test IE. 
Fix - Set the default video to mp4 and I used this code -

[video flv="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.flv" mp4="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/2012-reel.mp4" poster="http://www.parkmultimedia.com/flv/webstill.png" preload="true" autoplay="false" width="480" height="270"]

Using my iPod (yes pod, not pad) I get the play button with a line through it...though I also get the loading wheel...it just keeps loading.

Also, and I will search for this, but also an issue - in the new and old script I have autoplay set to false, but in Chrome and Safari it does it anyway. Is there an override setting or a way to control by browser?

Lastly, is there a way to center the player and not have it aligned left?

Thanks for any assistance, Dan